# Install OpenCV with Cuda support in Macports?

Tags: opencv, cuda, macports

I tried to use Macports to install Opencv 2.4.1 with CUDA support but with no luck.

The current version of port Opencv is 2.4.1. I can successfully install opencv and compile in Xcode, but when I tried to use gpu library, it says no gpu support.

According a the thread https://trac.macports.org/ticket/34753, version 2.4.1 in Macports should support cuda somehow, but I don't get it.

Is there a way to configure it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you use macports? Softforge tarball could be compiled under mac.

Answer (score 1):

You need OSX 10.7.3 and CUDA 4.1 (or above).

Comment: Thanks. I am using OSX 10.7.4 and CUDA 4.2. I solve the problem by install opencv with python27. It seems that only in this way it will compile opencv with cuda support. Now it works!